# How to work net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 correctly on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: networking, server, ip-forward

I tried to create a simple router on the ubuntu 20.04 LTS server, so firstly I checked `/etc/sysctl.conf` and `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`:

```
$cat /etc/sysctl.conf | grep ip_forward
#net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

$cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

I assumed the server already enabled IP forwarding according to this output, but IP forwarding didn't work. After that, I uncommented the line `#net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` and ran `sudo sysctl -p` but it didn't work yet.

```
$cat /etc/sysctl.conf | grep ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

$ sudo sysctl -p
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

It finally works after reboot but I can't figure out why running `sysctl -p` didn't enable IP forwarding. Also I discovered it can be disabled when I ran `echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` (and enabled after running `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`.)

Of course, IP forwarding was disabled when I changed `net.ipv4.ip_forward` to `0` and rebooted. However, it couldn't be enable even if I ran `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` or ran `sysctl -p` after changing `net.ipv4.ip_forward` to `1`.

Do I really need to reboot to enable `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you do `sysctl -p` it will reload `/etc/sysctl.conf` but it needs to be done after doing

```
sudo -i
```

press enter, your password, and issue the command on the `#` prompt. Do not do this with just `sudo`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What you are saying is to do `sudo -i sysctl -p` after changing `/etc/sysctl.conf`?

Comment: No. press enter after the `-i`. You need to do it on a `#` prompt